# Possible causes for network dropout

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

When transferring files between computers on my home network, after about 200-300MB, the desktop completely loses connectivity.  The only thing that solves the problem is to disable then re-enable the local network adapter.  This problem only came up about a month ago when I upgraded both systems to Win7 from XP64 and Vista 64.

So should I take it to mean that the network circuitry on my motherboard is going, and that I should switch to a NIC card?  This happens with two different routers, over wired or wireless connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try updating the drivers for your motherboard before fully replacing it. You could also try a cheap PCI NIC instead.